# Read the input till the "dot". Unknown size of string

Tags: c, string, scanf

I am trying to scanf the input document. It has the following format. N - number of strings in the file. And some strings (arithmetic expressions with integers) divided by the dot. I am writing the code, but the answer is incorrect.

```
    int N;
fscanf(input, "%i", &N);
int m=5,i;
char ch;
char expression[m];
for(i=0;ch!='.';i++){
    fscanf(input,"%c",&ch);
    expression[i]=ch;
}

printf("%s", expression);
```

Say, input is

```
52+3.
```

I.e. there is going to be 5 expressions, and first of them is (2+3).
The printed output for this part,however, is:

```
+3.
```

Any ideas where the mistake is?
Also, could you suggest a way to loop scaning the input? So that if N=5, it scanned document 5 times. It already is doing so, isn't it?

Comment: `fscanf(input, "%i", &N)` is consuming `"52"`, not just the `5`

Comment: Right! Thanks! somehow, i missed that. I changed that fscanf to fscanf(input, "%1i", &N);

Answer (score 1):

To make `fscanf` consume only 1 character when parsing an integer, do:

```
fscanf(input, "%1d", &N);
```

Also, your `expression` array contains room for only 5 characters.  Maybe you wanted to create an array of 5 character arrays (each with space for say 100 characters) so that you can read all of the expressions.

```
char expressions[5][100];
```

So that you can read the expressions in a loop:

```
int i;
int j;
int c;

for(i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    j = 0;
    while((c = fgetc(input)) != '.')
        expressions[i][j++] = c;
    expressions[i][j] = '\0';
}
```

Note that there is no error checking here, so if the input is bad, bad things will happen.

Answer (score 1):

**Code:**

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
main()
{
    FILE* input=fopen("new.txt","r");
    int N, n=1;
    int i;
    char line[80], *pLine=malloc(10);
    fscanf(input,"%d",&N);
    fscanf(input,"%s",line);
    pLine=strtok(line,".");
    while(n<=N)
    {
        printf("%s\n",pLine);
        pLine=strtok(NULL,".");
        n++;
    }
    fclose(input);
}
```

**File contents (new.txt):**

```
5
3+2.4+5.6+7.8+9.10+11.100+200
```

1. The file is scanned once for an integer `N` which specifies the no. of expressions to be scanned.
2. The next line containing the dot-separated expressions is scanned.
3. The line is broken down using `strtok()` with `"."` as the delimiter.

Comment: I am not confident with "malloc" and pointers yet. But thank you for suggestion!

Comment: i've used pointers for convenience of assignment, otherwise strcpy() must be used for char arrays...

Answer (score 1):

There are several things wrong with your program. While I am not completely sure I understand your specification, the first problem is that %i (you should probably use %d) will consume as many characters that appear to be a number.  So it is actually reading in 52 instead of 5 as you probably are expecting.  If you know that the value is a single digit then you could try using %1d as the first format statement "fscanf(input, "%1d", &N)". you are also not really doing anything with the value you put in N. I am also not sure why you use the number 5 in the third line.

In any case, here is a possibly solution (there are a lot of ways to do this). My solution works assuming I understand your problem statement although I don't do a lot of defensive programming. With languages like C and C++ you have to be careful when filling arrays that you don't exceed the arrays and write outside of memory that you have reserved for your buffers.

```
int n;
char buff[100];
fscanf(stdin, "%1d%s", &n, buff); /* %1d tells fscanf to read 1 integer character */
int i=0;
while(n) {
    while(buff[i] != '.') {
        putchar(buff[i]);
        i++;
    }
    i++; /* skip past '.' */
    --n;
    putchar('\n'); /* new line */
}
```

if your input were:

```
52+3.4+7.5+9.4+3.3+3.
```

then the output should be:

```
2+3
4+7
5+9
4+3
3+3
```

I am also assuming that the input is formatted correctly. In the real world you can't always
assume that and so you need to make sure that you don't do things like read past the buffer.  For instance if the last '.' were missing (or there were less '.' characters than the expression count (5) then the program would read past the end of the line and keep going until either it finds a '.' in random memory outside the buffer or you try to read memory that causes a program fault.

Comment: thanks, James! I used m=5, just as an example, because I did not come to the estimating the size of the expressions.
Could you explain your fscanf a little bit? As I understood buff is similar to my expression array. But what is stdin then? The document name from which input is read?

Comment: stdin, stdout and stderr are FILE pointers that are usually created by the runtime library. stdin is often keyboard, stdout is often the screen and stderr is a special output to the screen for errors.
fscanf requires at least 3 params but the number of params depends on the format string. %1d%s has 2. %1d will consume 1 character and attempt to convert it to an integer. %s will then consume strings until the end of line or spaces. In production code you would want to do a lot more checking than I did. fscanf has a useful return value for validity checking (num of fields scanned successfully)